# Login to multiple hosts and executing command in Unix

Tags: unix

i want to write script where it will login into 50 hosts and if login is successful it print message "login to host1 is 
successful" if not it should print message "Not able to login to host1". once connection to the host is succesful it should fire df command to check filesystem if df is stuck somewhere 
then it should print message "DF got stuck otherwise print message "DF is successful"

Please advice how should i achive this

i used below approach

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for i in `cat host.txt`

do

        ssh $i

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] then

        df

                if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] then
                return 0

                else

                echo "Something is wrong"

                fi
else

echo "not able to do df"


fi

done
```

Thanks

Comment: this is all nice, but why don't you use some monitoring tool, ganglia/munin/nagios/... ?

Comment: we need to check this after there are some changes made to system and then we just need to check whether login to all hosts are successful and filesystem is not affected due to any change.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in you script:

```
$ ssh loessl.org df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2           103212320  52448972  45520468  54% /
[..]
```

and/or have a look at [pconsole](http://www.heiho.net/pconsole/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a million solutions to this, all of them too large to fit into this tiny box. Which one is right for you depends on your tastes (I prefer Dancer's Shell for small groups of machines and simple tasks, but other tools for larger tasks on more machines)

https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/
http://rundeck.org/
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html
http://func.et.redhat.com/
http://docs.opscode.com/knife.html
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dsh/
http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page
http://cssh.sourceforge.net/

But this is not something you're going to be solve with a few lines of bash.

Comment: That's true - it's really just ssh in a for loop with a tiny bit of string processing, very easy to do in a few lines. Except that in my experience you can never get it to handle all the edge cases, so you end up spending more time trying to handle those than you would have done learning a solution that already handles those :)